# Model structure for Player Team and Match in football application

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

I'm creating an application for foosball matches.

I have models like below:

```
class Player(models.Model):
    match_amount = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    wins = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    avatar = models.ImageField(blank=True)
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        to=User,
        primary_key=True,
        related_name='player',
        verbose_name=_('user'),
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.get_full_name()


class Team(models.Model):
    players = models.ManyToManyField(Player)
    wins = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return "Team %s" % self.pk


class Match(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField(default=now)

    def __str__(self):
        return "Match on %s" % self.date


class TeamMatch(models.Model):
    team = models.ForeignKey(Team)
    match = models.ForeignKey(Match)

    points = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return "Match %s" % self.team
```

Is these models are well created?

Thanks much for each tip and corrections.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is difficult to say how good your models are, since it depends on your application requirements and demands, current and future/planned use cases.

But, few points from the top of my head:

- there are some important fields missing - for example, team names
- I don't particularly like the `TeamMatch` model. Instead, I'd expect the `Match` to have links to the home and away teams:

  ```
  class Match(models.Model):
      home_team = models.ForeignKey(Team, related_name='home_matches')
      away_team = models.ForeignKey(Team, related_name='away_matches')

      date = models.DateField(default=now)

      def __str__(self):
          return "Match between '%s' and '%s' on %s" % (self.home_team.name, self.away_team.name, self.date)
  ```
- you will also need some way of keeping the score of a match. A separate `MatchResult` model?
- how about a use case when a player moves from one team to another? If this is something you want to keep track of, you would probably need something like a `PlayerContract` model to relate players and teams for a certain period of time

Also, please see these similar model design discussions:

- [How should I design my django models for team, player and match objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15223126/how-should-i-design-my-django-models-for-team-player-and-match-objects)
- [Models for a team](https://www.reddit.com/r/django/comments/2ft4hl/models_for_a_team/)